# firebug [object CSSStyleRule]

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

In firebug (this started happening few days ago, i am not sure but i think it started after i updated firefox), when i inspect element with firebug and try to change css attribute in style view on the right i get "[object CSSStyleRule]" as a value of css attribute.

When i click on css file link and open whole css file i can change attribute values without this annoying braces.

I am using Firefox 17.0.1 and firebug 1.11.0

Did anybody have this issue lately and how did u managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known conflict between FireFile and Firebug 1.11. I suggest downgrading Firebug for now.